# Convert 201204121458 to date format 2012/04/12 14:59 in Java

Tags: java, datetime

I have an issue with java how can convert string 201204121458 to date format 2012/04/12 14:59 using a method ?

Thank you

Comment: Writing some code is a good start in most cases.

Comment: I guess "14:59" is a typo?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca or he is using 24h format ;)

Comment: @pikkuez 1458 to 14:59?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer haha ye im sorry :)

Comment: it's my fault 14:58 not 14:59

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet may help:

```
    String str = "201204121458";

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmm");
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);

    DateTimeFormatter printer = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
    String formattedDateTime = dateTime.format(printer); // "2012/04/12 14:59"
```

Comment: These terrible date-time classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Suggesting their use in 2020 is poor advice.

Comment: Don't think that it's really important if we speak about converting one date string to another date string. But generally you are right. The code snippet is adjusted.